# how to mimic 'not in' operation in hive while using custom udf in on clause?

Tags: hive

My hql is as follows:

**select cdo_oplog.operatorid, cdo_oplog.clientid from cdo_oplog left outer join inner_ip on StrContain(cdo_oplog.clientid, inner_ip.ip) where inner_ip.ip is null;**

As you can see, this hql can do the same thing as `not in` query in MySQL. But when I issue it in hive, the following error is thrown:

**FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:91 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'ip'**

When I googled about it, I find [a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017897/join-2-tables-in-hive-using-a-phone-number-and-a-prefix-variable-length), but the solution is only suitable for `in` query, not for `not in`. Could anyone give me an alternative for `not in` query in hive? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hive can not apply **StrContain(cdo_oplog.clientid, inner_ip.ip)** within the context of a join statement.

But it seems you already had realized that.  So maybe you would like to further your explain what you are expecting to achieve?

Comment: I intend to implement the `not in` query in hive, which can be seen at `where inner_ip.ip is null`.

Comment: Yes I understood that.  I have answered in the past how to do "in" (versus not in)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880124/hive-command-to-execute-not-in-clause/20885465#20885465

Comment: So is there an alternative for `not in` in this case which need udf at `on` clause?

Comment: No you are handling that part correctly.  The issue is that the joins in hive are strict/limited in what they allow. It is my understanding and experience they can not handle UDF's as you are trying.  YMMV.